# IUPAC naming of isocyanides

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC name of isocyanide : isonitrile or carbylamine?

Are "methyl isocyanide" and "carbylamine" the same thing?

Comment: Note that [carbylamines](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/C/C00853.html) is an obsolete and deprecated name for isocyanides (isonitriles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent IUPAC recommendations<sup>[1]</sup> states that:

> **P-61.9**: Preferred IUPAC names are formed substitutively using the prefix ‘isocyano’ attached directly to a parent hydride.

This is a change from previous recommendations, and differs from some of your examples above.

To give a concrete example, $\ce{C6H5NC}$ should be named `isocyanobenzene` - this is known as a [PIN by IUPAC](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/choice-of-preferred-iupac-names?rq=1) (preferred IUPAC name). Phenylisocyanide is also acknowledged as an acceptable trivial name (a name that does not conform to the recommendations but is still commonly used).

<sup>[1]: IUPAC Recommendations for Preferred Names 2013, Chapter P-6. DOI:10.1039/9781849733069-00648</sup>

Comment: Can I get an example of an open chain compound with isocyanide group IUPAC name attaching suffix

Comment: Isocyanoethane. The nomenclature system is universal, you just need to know the correct prefix.

Comment: Okay that means in case of isocyanide we will not use suffix but in case of cyanides we will still use the suffix "nitriles"