# Is toulene be a part of the systematic IUPAC name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Consider the following compound:

[image]

The name engraved below it is what ACD ChemSketch generated for me. However, my book mentions that "3-chlorotoluene" is the iupac name for this compound.

This is another compound:

[image]

My book mentions "2,4,6-trichlorotoluene" is the IUPAC name, while the above is the name generated by ChemSketch.

Now, I am confused as to which name to agree with.

> Which name is correct?
>   Which IUPAC rule says that toluene (and other related siblings like phenol) should be/should not be a part of the IUPAC name?

---

<sup>**NOTE:** I know that even [common names can be considered as PINs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/choice-of-preferred-iupac-names), but in my post I am dealing with systematic IUPAC name only.</sup>

Comment: Phenol is different, though... 4-chlorophenol is OK.

Comment: @orthocresol Is it preferred IUPAC or systematic IUPAC?

Comment: Yes, 4-chlorophenol is a PIN (P-63.1.1.1), whereas 4-chlorotoluene is not (explained in duplicate question). The reason is because phenol is designated as a preferred name which is substitutable at any position, whereas toluene is designated as a preferred name which cannot be substituted.

Comment: @orthocresol Ok. And are non-toluene names, like the one generated by ACD above, always valid and are correct IUPAC names?